# Adding multiples labels (views) side-by-side dinamically in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I would like to put programmatically buttons side-by-side in a cell and add actions, but firstly I am doing with UILabel to see how works. The problem is with UILabels isn't working.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let array = ["house", "bugs", "perl"] //comes from API
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DetailViewCell
    
    var hStackView = UIStackView()
    var vStackView = UIStackView()
    vStackView.axis = .vertical
    vStackView.spacing = 8
    vStackView.alignment = .top
    
    var count: Int = 0
    for ar in array {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 21)) //CGRectZero)
        label.text = ar
        label.textColor = .black
        
        if count % 2 == 0  {
            hStackView = UIStackView()
            hStackView.axis = .horizontal
            hStackView.spacing = 8
            hStackView.alignment = .fill
            hStackView.distribution = .fill
            hStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            if (count + 1) == array.count {
                vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
            }
        }
        else {
            hStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
        }
        count += 1
    }
    cell.addSubview(vStackView)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see anything because your vertical UIStackView does not know where it should be placed in your cell and how large it should be. You can do that with layout constraints:

```
vStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    cell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.leadingAnchor),
    cell.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.trailingAnchor),
    cell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.topAnchor),
    cell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

With the first line you tell it to use constraints for layouting. With the `NSLayoutConstraints.activate` you tell it how the vStackViews bounds are tied to the cell views bounds. In this case the vStackView now should take up the entire space provided by the cell.