# Dinamically fill UITableViewCell with buttons side by side

Tags: swift, uitableview

Continuing to resolve the task of [UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75473714/adding-multiples-labels-views-side-by-side-dinamically-in-uitableviewcell), I could fix all UIButtons side by side but they are not appearing properly in executing time. Sometimes the second row mix with the third.
I tryied with `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` but still wrong.

[image]

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DetailViewCell
let array = sections[indexPath.section].filters

var hStackView = UIStackView()
var vStackView = UIStackView()
vStackView.axis = .vertical
vStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
vStackView.spacing = 12
vStackView.alignment = .top

for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle(item.title, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220, green: 220, blue: 220)
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.tag = index
    
    if index % 2 == 0  {
        hStackView = UIStackView()
        hStackView.axis = .horizontal
        hStackView.spacing = 12
        hStackView.alignment = .fill
        hStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        if (index + 1) == array.count {
            vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
            hStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            hStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        }
    }
    else {
        hStackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
        hStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
cell.addSubview(vStackView)
vStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    cell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: -8),
    cell.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    cell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.topAnchor, constant: -8),
    cell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
])
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up information about `dequeueReusableCell`

It works somehow like this: when you get a cell in `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` from `dequeueReusableCell` you are provided with a ready-made cell that was used somewhere. It follows from this that all content that the cells differ in must be placed in the cell only in this method

Note, the button with a label сссс is clearly from the top cell

I would advise you to declare in your `UITableViewCell` subclass a method in which you put content inside and call it every time inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

You can use a storyboard if you like, but if you want to do it with code, I can suggest custom `UITableViewCell` subclass template:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Public methods
    
    func setContent(_ content: <# ContentType #>) {
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private setup methods
    
    private func setupView() {
        
        makeConstraints()
    }
    
    private func makeConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but still repeating the cell values, now as a button sum effect. It seems like you have to restart the viewcell before each interaction. How to solve?

Comment: When you call setContent method you need to clear all old content
This might help in your case

stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }